# Global logrotate.conf not considering logs

Tags: logging, global, logrotate

Noob here (Ubuntu 20.04). I have multiple logs that currently have logrotate config files included in `/etc/logrotate.d`. I want all logs to follow global logrotate settings (`/etc/logrotate.conf`) so I can maintain everything in one place, specifying log-specific directives where needed. One of these logs is **`/var/log/apt/history.log`**, which is not included when I run logrotate in debug mode.

1. I removed the non-global config file - `/etc/logrotate.d/apt` - that should have taken precedence over the global logrotate.conf file.
2. I updated `/etc/logrotate.conf` with the following directives to test whether or not `/var/log/apt/history.log` was leveraging the global conf file or not:

> ```
> /var/log/apt/history.log {
> rotate 12
> hourly
> missingok
> delaycompress
> }
> ```

3. When debugging, the log is not included. After waiting several hours for logrotate to run natively, nothing happens. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by waiting overnight. My best guess: since the log was already rotated once in the day, despite including directives for hourly rotation and using the `--force` command when debugging, `/var/log/apt/history.log`, the logs still weren't considered for rotation.

From **`man logrotate`**:

> Normally, logrotate is run as a daily cron job. **It will not modify a log multiple  times in one day** unless the criterion for that log is based on the log's size and  logrotate is being run multiple times each day, or unless the -f or --force option  is used.